# How to determine ordering of event listeners in Javascript

Tags: javascript, event-handling, dom-events

I'm confused by the ordering of event listeners in Javascript. If I have a form with a submit button and I'd like to alert a user instead of automatically submitting the form, but only when the submit using the Enter key, I can create an event listener for an Enter keypress, event.preventDefault(), etc.

Why is it that the default `onsubmit` event listener for the form is not triggered first?

Comment: Keyboard and mouse events have to be triggered first, because they can use `event.preventDefault()` to prevent them from being turned into a form submit.

Comment: Can you explain why you would expect the `submit` event to be triggered first?

Comment: The direct answer to the question is "by reading the W3C DOM spec", where sequences of events resulting from user (or other) interaction are described.

Answer (score 0):

Events do follow the [law of causality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Causality). Smaller primitives build up larger, more important ones:

- keydown -> keyup -> keypress -> change
- mousedown -> mouseup -> click -> submit

In your case, the <kbd>Enter</kbd> keypress event **causes** the submit event.

Preventing the default action of an event will suppress the ensuing ones. They can't happen in reverse.